# Open Image in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to add similar functionality to mobile safari. That is, when a user tap and holds on an image in the `UIWebView`, I would like an option to pop up to open the image url in the `UIWebView`. Similar to how you right click on an image in a browser on your computer and choose "Open Image in new tab/new window". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView - Enabling Action Sheets on <img> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163831/uiwebview-enabling-action-sheets-on-img-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this tutorial:
http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/.

credit goes to:
[UIWebView - Enabling Action Sheets on <img> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163831/uiwebview-enabling-action-sheets-on-img-tags)