# Detecting Images in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview

As part of the app I'm working on, users need to be able to import images from a variety of places, including downloading them from the web.  I've added an in-app browser, and included a context-sensitive menu to present the users with different options when they long-press on a particular item.

My code uses Javascript to detect the tags of HTML elements, and is based on the following tutorial and SO post:

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/

[UIWebView - Enabling Action Sheets on <img> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163831/uiwebview-enabling-action-sheets-on-img-tags/5607694#5607694)

The following method is called by a UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
(void)openContextMenuAt:(CGPoint)pt
{
    // Load the JavaScript code from the Resources and inject it into the web page
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSTools" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsCode];

    // get the Tags and URL at the touch location
    NSString *tags = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyAppGetHTMLElementsAtPoint(%i,%i);",(NSInteger)pt.x,(NSInteger)pt.y]];
    NSString *elementURL = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyAppGetLinkHREFAtPoint(%i,%i);", (NSInteger)pt.x, (NSInteger)pt.y]];

    // create the UIActionSheet and populate it with buttons related to the tags
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:elementURL
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    BOOL shouldShowMenu = NO;

    // If a link was touched, add link-related buttons
    if ([tags rangeOfString:@",A,"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Open", nil)];
        shouldShowMenu = YES;
    }

    // If an image was touched, add image-related buttons
    if ([tags rangeOfString:@",IMG,"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Save Image", nil)];
        shouldShowMenu = YES;
    }

    // check the item to see if it has an audio link attached
    NSSet *validAudioExtensions = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"aiff", @"aac", @"alac", @"m4a", @"mp3", @"raw", @"wav", nil];
    NSString *urlSuffix = [[elementURL pathExtension] lowercaseString];
    if ([validAudioExtensions containsObject:urlSuffix]) {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Save Audio"];
        shouldShowMenu = YES;
    }

    // Add buttons which should be always available
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Open in Safari", nil)];

    if (shouldShowMenu == YES)
    {
        CGRect menuTarget = CGRectMake(pt.x, pt.y, 1, 1);
        [sheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];
        [sheet showFromRect:menuTarget inView:self.webView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Until recently, this worked perfectly on almost every site I tested.  However, it has since stopped working on Google's image search (which, unfortunately, is the first place most users will probably look).

On the main search results (with the image thumbnails), I'm able to detect the IMG tag and download the thumbnail image.  However, if I tap on the thumbnail to bring up the larger, full-sized image, I can no longer detect what I am pressing.  Additionally, I am unable to retrieve the URL from either view (printing the url only showed an empty string).

Is there an alternate, better method for detecting which element was pressed?  Is there a specific work-around I need to use for Google?

Thanks in advance for your help.