# Tap and hold save image from UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, save

I want to be able to save an image to the photos app from a `UIWebView` when the user taps and holds on the image.

I've managed to save an image from a `UIWebView` when I was programming in objective-c however now as I'm learning swift it seems to be kind of different.

This is how I did it back in Objective-C:

```
-(IBAction)saveWeb:(id)sender 
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.frame.size);
    [self.webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil,nil,nil); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you have right now is more towards taking a screen shot of the web page.

You can combine gesture recognizers and Javascript to get an image at a give point in a HTML page..

Have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607694/4236572 . You may want to implement something like that..