# Unable to save an image in webview in ios

Tags: ios, object

We are developing an iOS app.In my app I need to redirect to a weblink. For that I am using webview. Now, my requirement is to save an image in that web site. But I am unable to save an image. It is getting saved when I am redirecting it to safari browser. But my client is not accepting if it is redirecting to safari browser. So my question is , is it possible to save an image with in app webview?  Thanks for your valuable suggestion in advance.

Comment: How the image is saved via Safari Browser? Is it saved from code or by user action?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607694/5060335)

Comment: @EugeneDubinin thanks for the response. Image is saving by user action not through programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can.I have written a category for `UIWebView` to enable saving image in `UIWebView` to system album.Please check this [UIWebView-ImageSaver](https://github.com/tounaobun/UIWebView-ImageSaver) out.Just import those files into your project and call `enableLongPressingToSaveImage` method in `viewDidLoad` method or else.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    // Long pressing the image area,and it would be saved to system album.
    [webView enableLongPressingToSaveImage];
}
```