# How to save Image from UIWebView in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on Browser application. I want to save image when user tap on an Image on UIWebView. I checked NavigationType of UIWebView.

When I click on an image on an UIWebView it does not return to any delegate method for UIWebView.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can try to follow this answer it may help you . [UIwebview save image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607694/6628878)

Comment: @matt then how can we get user action on image tap?